# Why Golang hchan struct closed field use uint32 type?

Tags: go

```golang
type hchan struct {
    qcount   uint           // total data in the queue
    dataqsiz uint           // size of the circular queue
    buf      unsafe.Pointer // points to an array of dataqsiz elements
    elemsize uint16
    closed   uint32
....
```

I searched the references of all `closed` fields, the values are only 0 and 1. What is more confusing is why not use int8 or other types?

[image]

Comment: Did you check to see how that field is accessed/modified in the source code? (Atomics only support specific data types)

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I uploaded screenshots of all references to closed, it seems that there are no other values using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why Golang hchan struct closed field use uint32 type [instead of uint8]?

Ask yourself:

- What would be gained by using uint8? (Hint: nothing)
- Would using uint8 make the code more complicated? (Hint: yes)

Sometimes there are no "deep" reasons. uint32 works well and is fine.

Comment: There's a deleted answer that points out the history here as well: in very early days of Go, the field was `uint32` as the only atomic ops were for `uint32`. As the compiler and runtime have to coordinate, it's messy to make any changes here'; since there is no *pressure* to change it, it stays.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself:

- What you're trying to achieve?

Using uint32 is also fine. I recommend you to read these two articles [(1)](https://golangbyexample.com/all-data-types-in-golang-with-examples/#Integers_Signed_and_UnSigned) [(2)](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/3) that will briefly explain the data types.